# I am wondering why my program is giving wrong outputs for over 40 and 50 hours?

Tags: python

I am doing a project that requires overtime to be 1.5 and anything after 50 is double time. When I do 55x15.50 I get 1240 and for 45x20.75 I will get 985.62 which is the right amount but the taxes and net amount is wrong.

```
GrossPay = Hourly * RateofPay
Taxes = GrossPay * 0.4
NetPay = GrossPay - Taxes

if Hourly <= 40:
       (Hourly * RateofPay)

   else:
         GrossPay = 40 * RateofPay + (Hourly-40)*RateofPay*1.5 

 if Hourly > 50:
            GrossPay = 50 * RateofPay + (Hourly-50)*RateofPay*2

print("The gross pay is: $", format(GrossPay, '.2f'))
print("The taxes are: $", format(Taxes, '.2f'))
print("The net pay is: $", format(GrossPay-Taxes, '.2f'))
```

Comment: *"but the taxes and net amount is wrong."* What is the expected output and what is the actual output? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I've edited to try to fix the code formatting, but it's unclear what the intention was. Please fix the formatting to match your actual code.

Comment: You are calculating `Taxes` and `NetPay` at the beginning before your `GrossPay` calculation. Calculate them after the `if` loop to get accurate results.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single line of code without the need of if else statements:

```
gross_pay = (max(hours-50,0)*2 + max(min(10,hours-40),0)*1.5 + min(hours, 40)) * hourly_wage
taxes = gross_pay * 0.4
net_pay = gross_pay - taxes
```

Comment: If I do this the overtime or double time won't be added in.

Comment: Yes it does, it double all hours over 50, 1.5 times all hours between 40 and 50 and all other hours as single hours. So for 55 hours it would be `5*2 + 10*1.5 + 40` and for e.g. 47 it would be `0*2 + 7 *1.5 + 40`. I believe this is what you wanted

Comment: That is what I am wanting. Thank You! I was able to get it with this. I appreciate the help.